# jQuery Fade In/Out Image Background Glitch

Tags: jquery, css, image, button, fade

I have a specific area in my site with a toggle-able background but it seems to be a bit glitchy. My code works when it comes to fading in-out other objects but in this case it doesn't work with my images.
**What I want:** Whenever the user clicks on my button the functions is activated. If the "buttons" text is "Apps" I want the background to fade out and if it is "Games" to fade back in. In the same time I want the text's color class to change as well from `fontcolor2` to `fontcolor1` and the other way around.
**Problem;** When I run the code works on the first click. After that the background fades out like normally and the text changes. But when I click the changed button the color of the text changes without my images fading back in.

The image that is glitching is called `gamesBG` and the time is `bgFadeDuration`.

**Here's my code;**

```
$('#togglega').click(function(){
    var bgFadeDuration = 300;
    if ($('#togglega:contains(Apps)')) {
        $('#nothingyet').css('display', 'none');
        jQuery('#gamesBG').fadeOut(bgFadeDuration);
        $("#togglega").toggleClass('fontcolor2 fontcolor1');
        $("#sqtitle").toggleClass('fontcolor2 fontcolor1');
        $("#sl1ndp").toggleClass('fontcolor2 fontcolor1');
        $("#swtitle").toggleClass('fontcolor2 fontcolor1');
        $("#squl").toggleClass('fontcolor2 fontcolor1');
    } else if ($('#togglega:contains(Games)')){
        $('#nothingyet').css('display', 'block');
        jQuery('#gamesBG').fadeIn(bgFadeDuration);
        $("#togglega").toggleClass('fontcolor1 fontcolor2');
        $("#sqtitle").toggleClass('fontcolor1 fontcolor2');
        $("#sl1ndp").toggleClass('fontcolor1 fontcolor2');
        $("#swtitle").toggleClass('fontcolor1 fontcolor2');
        $("#squl").toggleClass('fontcolor1 fontcolor2');
        jQuery('#bttimg1').css('opacity', '0');
        jQuery('#bttimg2').css('opacity', '0.7');
        jQuery('.gdb').css('color', '#212121');
    } else {

    }
});
```

Where's the problem and why is my code not working?

**UPDATE**
I change the text from `Apps` to `Games` by using a Javascript function. The function is the following;

**Javascript**

```
function togglegaclick(){
this.GamesChange = function(){
    togglebutton.innerHTML = 'Games';
    document.getElementById('towlabel').style.left = "60px";
    categorylabel.innerHTML = 'Apps';
    categorylabel.style.top = "17px";
    categorylabel.style.left = "100px";
}
this.AppsChange = function(){
    togglebutton.innerHTML = 'Apps';
    document.getElementById('towlabel').style.left = "45px";
    categorylabel.innerHTML = 'Games';
    categorylabel.style.top = "20px";
    categorylabel.style.left = "80px";
}
this.TitleFadeOut = function(){
    fadeEffect.init('toqlabel', 1, 0);
    fadeEffect.init('sqtitle', 1, 0);
}
this.TitleFadeIn = function(){
    fadeEffect.init('toqlabel', 1, 100);
    fadeEffect.init('sqtitle', 1, 100);
}
var togglebutton = document.getElementById('toqlabel');
var categorylabel = document.getElementById('sqtitle');
var gamesbox = document.getElementById('gamesbox');
if (togglebutton.innerHTML == 'Apps'){
    GamesChange();
}else{
    AppsChange();

}
```

}

Comment: I'm still working on your issue and may have reproduced the problem. I'm confused though about your "button" - how does the text change from Apps to Games? Or are there two buttons?

Comment: @TimSPQR I am using a Javascript function to change the text from "Apps" to "Games" on both the button and the text displayed. I'll post my Javascript function on my question for you to see.

Comment: Ok, all in pure JS...still working on it...minor typo - change toqlabel to towlabel. Probably not the cause...Here's a fiddle I'm working on http://jsfiddle.net/pBE2S/

Comment: I've looked at everything and I've only noted that it is difficult to fade a background image vs a foreground image. Also I put alerts as the first command in each of your functions and only the Gameschange and Appschange functions fired. So I think some more debugging is necessary - maybe just cut the code down to the bare necessity and build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see if this is what you're looking for - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sP77L/2/).

I switched the selector to .html() and added .fadeToggle.

JS

```
var bgFadeDuration = 1000;

$('#togglega').on('click', function(){

    if( $("#togglega").text() == "Games" )
    {
     $('#nothingyet').css('display', 'block');
     $("#togglega").toggleClass('fontcolor1 fontcolor2');
     $('#gamesBG').fadeToggle(bgFadeDuration);
     }
     else if ( $("#togglega").text() == "Apps" )
   {
     $('#nothingyet').css('display', 'none');
     $('#gamesBG').fadeOut(bgFadeDuration);
     $("#togglega").toggleClass('fontcolor2 fontcolor1');
    }

                                        });
```

Comment: That isn't what I am looking for. I updated my question by adding some Javascript to help you understand.